# screen time report in iOS

Tags: ios, swift

How can I get a report in my iOS app with the information that appears in iOS 12 on screen time? Is there an API or does anyone know how to access the information?

[image: apple screen time]

Comment: I might be wrong but this is personal information and I don't think Apple would allow your App to access it. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/103745

Comment: It's a really good question, but SO thinks otherwise....

Comment: @houman actually a bad question. Its too broad and a simple google search will show that you cannot even access application names, not even speaking about system statistics.

Comment: @Sulthan I don't think the question is broad. Back then I googled and came across this and found it useful. I think, there are no dumb questions, but there are dumb answers. Sadly SO goes sometimes with the latter.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API for Screen Time, and due to "Sandboxing" of apps in iOS you cannot get data of other apps, though you can request an API is developed in the future [here](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/).